# MPandroid Onclicklistener is not working

Tags: java, mpandroidchart

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Description;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.PercentFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartValueSelectedListener;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
private float[] yData = {10,15,140}; //numbers of each type
private String[] xData = {"Low","Medium","High"};
PieChart pieChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.idPieChart);
    //pieChart.getDescription().setText("Numbers of Vul chart");
    //pieChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));

    pieChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
    pieChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);

    pieChart.setHoleRadius(40f);
    pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(0);
    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    pieChart.setCenterText("Percentage of Types");
    pieChart.setCenterTextSize(11);
    pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(true);

    appDataSet();


    pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: Value select from chart.");
            Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: " + e.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: " + h.toString());

            int pos1 = e.toString().indexOf("(sum): ");
            String select = e.toString().substring(pos1 + 3);

           for(int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++){
                if(yData[i] == Float.parseFloat(select)){
                    pos1 = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            String types = xData[pos1 + 1];
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vulnerability type: " + types + "\n" + "Total:" + select, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });

}
private void appDataSet() {
    ArrayList<PieEntry> yEntrys = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> xEntrys = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i< yData.length; i++)
    {
        yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i], i));
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < xData.length; i++)
    {
        xEntrys.add(xData[i]);
    }

    PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yEntrys, "Types of Vulnerability");
    pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(3);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add(Color.rgb(255,253,71));  //Yellow
    colors.add(Color.rgb(255,191,71)); //Orange
    colors.add(Color.rgb(255,99,99)); //red

    pieDataSet.setColors(colors);

    Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);
    legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART);

    PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
    pieData.setValueTextSize(15f);
    pieData.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    pieChart.setData(pieData);
    pieChart.invalidate();


}
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to touch on each pie and I don't know what is the problem in my code. Moreover, I've learned this code from this link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BcTXbwDGbg

The other way to use onclicklistener is not working to me either

```
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

    if (e == null)
        return;
    Log.i("VAL SELECTED",
            "Value: " + e.getVal() + ", xIndex: " + e.getXIndex()
                    + ", DataSet index: " + dataSetIndex);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {
    Log.i("PieChart", "nothing selected");
}
```

It does not know dataSetIndex